# Partial Differentiation with interpolation function

Tags: interpolation, vector-calculus

I'm trying to take the partial differential of each component of an interpolation summed together. It works fine when I do it with an algebraic expression, but I can't understand why it doesn't work with the interpolation function.

Defining the magnetic field algebraically:

```
u = 1;

(*define magnetic field*) 

bfield[x_, y_, z_] = {y/1, (x*3^2)/1, 0};


(*calculate magnetic pressure*) 

pfield[x_, y_, z_] = {

-D[1/(2 u) (\[Sqrt]((bfield[x, y, z][[1]])^2 + (bfield[x, y, z][[
        2]])^2 + (bfield[x, y, z][[3]])^2))^2, x],

-D[1/(2 u) (\[Sqrt]((bfield[x, y, z][[1]])^2 + (bfield[x, y, z][[
        2]])^2 + (bfield[x, y, z][[3]])^2))^2, y],

-D[1/(2 u) (\[Sqrt]((bfield[x, y, z][[1]])^2 + (bfield[x, y, z][[
        2]])^2 + (bfield[x, y, z][[3]])^2))^2, z]};


VectorPlot3D[pfield[x, y, z], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, {z, -3, 3}]

StreamPlot[{pfield[x, y, z][[1]], pfield[x, y, z][[2]]}, {x, -3,3}, {y, -3, 3}]
```

But now I try the same thing with the interpolation function (I need to use the interpolation function as I will change the data eventually and thus it will have no simple algebraic function)

```
testdata = 

Flatten[Table[N@{x, y, z, bfield[x, y, z]}, {x, -3, 3 , 0.5}, {y, -3, 3 ,0.5}, ,{z, 0, 1, 0.5}], 2];

intf = Interpolation[testdata];

intfpressure[x_, y_, z_] := Module[{r = intf[x, y, z]}, {

(-D[1/(2 u) (\[Sqrt]((r[[1]])^2 + (r[[2]])^2 + (r[[3]])^2))^2, x]),

(-D[1/(2 u) (\[Sqrt]((r[[1]])^2 + (r[[2]])^2 + (r[[3]])^2))^2, y]),

(-D[1/(2 u) (\[Sqrt]((r[[1]])^2 + (r[[2]])^2 + (r[[3]])^2))^2, z])}];


VectorPlot3D[intfpressure[x, y, z], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, {z, 0, 1},

ViewPoint -> {0, 0, 200}, VectorPoints -> Fine, 

PlotLabel -> "pressure"]

StreamPlot[{intfpressure[x, y, 0][[1]], intfpressure[x, y, 0][[2]]}, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}
```

And I get the correct fields from first code snippet:

[image]

[image]

Wrong from the second:

[image]

[image: ]]

Extension of this question: [Picking a dimension from an interpolating function](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/119396/picking-a-dimension-from-an-interpolating-function)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with your second code block is that `r[[1]], r[[2]]` etc. are not the first, second etc. components of the vector field as you would expect.

If you input numerical values for `x, y, z` in `intfpressure`, e.g. `intfpressure[0,0,0]`, then `r` is just a list of three *numbers*, so differentiating the elements of this list with respect to either of the coordinates will just give 0. On the other hand, if we call `intfpressure` with symbolic arguments, then `r` just stays unevaluated, just as if we had called `intf[x,y,z]`:[image]

This is actually what happens inside `VectorPlot3D`; *Mathematica* first tries to evaluate the expression to plot with symbolic arguments, and only later assigns numerical values to them in order to plot something. Now, taking the `Part`s, `[[1]]` or `[[2]]` etc., of such an expression as `intf[x,y,z]` is the same as taking the parts of any other expression with an arbitrary head:

```
dummyhead[x,y,z][[1]]
(* x *)
```

[image]

This explains your incorrect vector plot; the thing you are differentiating in `intfpressure`, `Sqrt[r[[1]]^2 + r[[2]]^2 + r[[3]]^2]^2` is nothing but `Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + z^2]^2`, which is of course not what you want.

My proposed fix is to use `Derivative` to produce the interpolations to the partial derivatives, since `Derivative` is, as the documentation says,

> a functional operator which acts on functions to give derivative
>   functions.

Here is the code. I've made a helper function `intfnorm` to show how one can use `FunctionInterpolation` to create new `InterpolatingFunction`s from other such objects, and to improve readability:

```
intfnorm = 
 FunctionInterpolation[
  intf[x, y, z].intf[x, y, z], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, {z, 0, 1}]

Clear[intfpressure]

intfpressure[x_, y_, 
  z_] :=
 (-1/(2 u)) {Derivative[1, 0, 0][intfnorm][x, y, z],
   Derivative[0, 1, 0][intfnorm][x, y, z],
   Derivative[0, 0, 1][intfnorm][x, y, z]}

StreamPlot[{intfpressure[x, y, 0][[1]], 
  intfpressure[x, y, 0][[2]]}, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}]
```

[image]